# Android app that sends query string over HTTP and POST

Tags: android, sockets, http, post, base64

i am developing a file manager Android app that sends a base64 encoded file to a web server via the POST method. On the server side a cgi perl script gets the string, decodes it and saves it to a file. The problem is that the socket connection could not be established and there is no data entry in the Apache access log. Please share any ideas, here are the source codes:

"i" is an object of class Item - that is the selected file from the file manager.

Item i = adapter.getItem(position);
I am passing "i" to the sendFile method.

```
private void sendFile(Item i) {
    try {
        File inFile;
        DataInputStream dis;
        String queryString, encodedData, headerPart1, headerPart2, dataBundle;
        byte[] fileData;
        int contentLength;
        String host = "192.168.100.2";

        inFile = new File(i.getPath());
        fileData = new byte[(int) inFile.length()];
        dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(i.getPath()));
        dis.readFully(fileData);
        dis.close();

        encodedData = Base64.encodeToString(fileData, Base64.NO_WRAP);

        AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager
                .get(getBaseContext());
        Account account = getAccount(accountManager);

        queryString = account.name + "^" + i.getName() + "^" + encodedData;

        headerPart1 = "POST /cgi-bin/grabber.cgi HTTP/1.1\r\n" + "Host: "
                + host + "\r\n" + "User-Agent: Tposter\r\n"
                + "Content-Length: ";
        headerPart2 = "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n"
                + "Accept-Charset: UTF-8\r\n\r\n";

        contentLength = queryString.length();
        dataBundle = headerPart1 + contentLength + "\r\n" + headerPart2
                + queryString;

        // Create file uploader thread
        FileUploader fileUploader = new FileUploader(dataBundle);
        fileUploader.start();
        Toast.makeText(this, "File sent!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("send ERROR in file FileChooser.class ", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

FileUploader.java

```
public class FileUploader extends Thread {

PrintWriter printWriter;
SocketAddress sockAddr;
Socket socket;
int port = 80;
String host = "192.168.100.2";

public FileUploader(String dataBundle) {
    try {
        sockAddr = new InetSocketAddress(host, port);
        socket = new Socket();
        socket.setSoTimeout(3000);
        socket.connect(sockAddr, 5000);
        if (socket.isConnected()) {
            Log.w("Connected! ", dataBundle);

            printWriter = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                    socket.getOutputStream()));

            printWriter.println(dataBundle);
            printWriter.flush();
            printWriter.close();
            socket.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("socket ERROR in file fileUploader.class ", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

![SCREENSHOT of the debug]: (http://postimg.org/image/6upsjregb/)

Comment: why would you use sockets to do REST based communication when [android comes with several HTTP clients built in](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.nz/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html)?

Comment: Why are you base64 encoding the file data? I would suggest sending the raw file data as-is. To help facilitate that, move `account.name` to a custom HTTP header, like `X-AccountName`, and move `i.getName()` to the `name` parameter of the `Content-Type` header. You can then utilize HTTP 1.1's `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` header (and omit the `Content-Length` header) so you can read and send the raw file data in chunks to reduce memory usage and not read the entire file into memory anymore.

Comment: I am encoding the file in order to send binary files over HTTP, but please focus on the problem. I will try the HTTP clients. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I use httpClient to accomplish this. The below example sends and wait for receipt of JSON data from my server.

```
private String postPullData(JSONObject json, String URL) throws JSONException { 
    HttpClient httpclient;
    int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 20*1000;
    int WAIT_RESPONSE_TIMEOUT = 20*1000;
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);

    String Error = "SCOMM Error: ";
    JSONArray postjson;
    URL url = null;

    int sdkVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

    /*
     *  according to the Android docs, Android 3.0+ should use URLConnection
     *  but I can't get that to work. For now, keep using HttpConnection

    if (sdkVersion < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    */
        // use the older HttpClient 

        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, WAIT_RESPONSE_TIMEOUT);
        HttpConnectionParams.setTcpNoDelay(httpParameters, true);

        httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);


        try {

            postjson = new JSONArray();
            postjson.put(json);

            // Post the data:
            httppost.setHeader("json", json.toString());
            httppost.getParams().setParameter("jsonpost", postjson);

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            System.out.print(json);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            // for JSON:
            if (response != null)
            {
                InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(is));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                try {
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Error += " IO Exception: " + e;
                    Log.d("SCOMM", Error);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return Error;
                } finally {
                    try {
                        is.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {

                        Error += " closing connection: " + e;
                        Log.d("SCOMM", Error);
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        return Error;
                    }
                }

                return sb.toString();

 <snip>
```